# Write value from text box into cell only if textbox is not empty

Tags: vba, excel

- I am searching solutions for three problems i am facing in VBA 1st is

  - I have a userform with some text boxes. values inserted in that text boxes are to be added in some specific cells
- but what i want is, if cell has a value but text box is empty then consider that cell value

I have tried following code but it results in empty cell,pls help me on this

```
If IsEmpty(("B4")) = False And Me.TextBox_applied_date.value = 0 Then
    Me.TextBox_applied_date.value = ws.Cells(4, 2).value Else
    ws.Cells(4, 2).value = Me.TextBox_applied_date.value
End If
```

- 2nd problem is i have following code in my userform, when i exeute below code caps lock and num lock automatically gets turn off and turn on i want to stop this.

  ```
  ws.Cells(3, 2).value = Me.TextBox_company_name.value

  If Not Me.TextBox_applied_date.value = vbNullString Then
      ws.Cells(4, 2).value = Me.TextBox_applied_date.value
  End If


  If Not Me.TextBox_allotmenr_date.value = vbNullString Then
      ws.Cells(3, 9).value = Me.TextBox_allotmenr_date.value
  End If

  If Not Me.TextBox_listing_date.value = vbNullString Then
      ws.Cells(4, 9).value = Me.TextBox_listing_date.value
  End If

  Me.TextBox_applied_date.value = ""
  Me.TextBox_allotmenr_date = ""
  Me.TextBox_listing_date = ""
  Me.TextBox_company_name.SetFocus
  Unload Me
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ```
- and the last problem is, i want to sort sheets by colour, date mentioned in specific cell for e.g.

  "b4" or by name, so how can i do that

any help will be appriciated heartly.thank you.

Comment: Firstly consider Not IsEmpty rather than IsEmpty = False

Comment: Did you actually mean If Not IsEmpty(("B4")) And Me.TextBox_applied_date.Value = vbNullString Then
    Me.TextBox_applied_date.Value = ws.Cells(4, 2).Value

Comment: Well this code does not turn off/on capslock or numlock. This must be something else but not that code.

Comment: i have searched for turn on/off capslock or num lock automatically most of person says its due to sendkey function and use it as last resort

Comment: Well you cannot ask more and more in the same question. Please open up a completely new question. This has nothing to do with your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

If textbox is not empty then write value into cell, otherwise do nothing.

```
If Not Me.TextBox_applied_date.value = vbNullString Then
    ws.Cells(4, 2).value = Me.TextBox_applied_date.value
End If
```

Comment: yes brother thank you a lot for making it quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after something like:

```
If Not IsEmpty(("B4")) And Me.TextBox_applied_date.Value = vbNullString Then Me.TextBox_applied_date = .Value = ws.Cells(4, 2).Value
```